# I am unable to connect my register page in react to API

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is the code snippet for register page which I am trying to connect to API but there is an error coming in the console. I have already connected nodejs with MongoDB successfully but not able to connect frontend (react) with backend.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
const Login = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const collectdata = async () => {
    console.warn(name, email, password);
    let result = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/register", {
      method: "post",
      body: JSON.stringify({ name, email, password }),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    });
    result = await result.json();
    console.warn(result);
  };
  return (
    <div className="login">
      <h2>register</h2>

      <input
        className="inputbox"
        type="text"
        value={name}
        onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
        placeholder="enter name"
      />
      <input
        className="inputbox"
        type="text"
        value={email}
        onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
        placeholder="enter email"
      />
      <input
        className="inputbox"
        type="password"
        value={password}
        onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
        placeholder="enter password"
      />
      <button className="button" type="button" onClick={collectdata}>
        signup
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Login;
```

[image]

This error is coming in my console.

Comment: Are you able to connect to the same endpoint using curl OR API platforms like postman?

Answer (score 0):

The only error I can see in your code is that you are not checking the status of the response from the fetch() call. If the response is not successful, then you should handle the error accordingly.

Here is a modified version of your code that checks the status of the response:

```
    import React, { useState } from "react";
    import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

const Login = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const collectdata = async () => {
    console.warn(name, email, password);
    let response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/register", {
      method: "post",
      body: JSON.stringify({ name, email, password }),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    });

    if (!response.ok) {
      // Handle the error here
      console.error("Error:", response.statusText);
      return;
    }

    let result = await response.json();
    console.warn(result);
  };

  return (
    <div className="login">
      <h2>register</h2>

      <input
        className="inputbox"
        type="text"
        value={name}
        onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
        placeholder="enter name"
      />
      <input
        className="inputbox"
        type="text"
        value={email}
        onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
        placeholder="enter email"
      />
      <input
        className="inputbox"
        type="password"
        value={password}
        onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
        placeholder="enter password"
      />
      <button className="button" type="button" onClick={collectdata}>
        signup
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```